How can I select Approving date if the report exists on report table?
I need to SELECT order date , scan date and report date from 3 tables
this is the QUERY :
SELECT   H.PATIENT_NO,
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(H.SERV_REQUEST_DATE,'yyyymmdd'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Order Date",
         (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(H.SERV_REQUEST_TIME),4,'0'),'HH24MI'),'HH24:MI')) AS "Order Time" , 
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(G.DATE_IMAGE_TAKEN,'yyyymmdd'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Scan Date",
         (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(G.TIME_IMAGE_TAKEN),4,'0'),'HH24MI'),'HH24:MI')) AS "Scan Time" , 
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(R.APPROVING_DATE,'yyyymmdd'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Release Date",
         (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(r.approving_time),4,'0'),'HH24MI'),'HH24:MI')) AS "Release Time" , 
          H.PATIENT_SOURCE_IND,
          H.PROVIDING_RESOURCE                 
     FROM   RAD_RESULT_VIEW H,RAD_IMAGE_HEADER G, RAD_REPORT_RESULT R , MR_FILE_DETAILS A
     WHERE  H.HOSPITAL_NO = G.HOSPITAL_NO
            AND H.HOSPITAL_NO = M.HOSPITAL_NO
            AND H.PATIENT_NO = A.PATIENT_NO
            AND H.RAD_ORDER_NO = G.RAD_ORDER_NO
            AND (G.IMAGE_NO = R.IMAGE_NO)

Not all orders have a report in table RAD_REPORT_RESULT
So what I need how to select R.APPROVING_DATE and R.approving_time only if there is a report exist
with this option
 AND (G.IMAGE_NO = R.IMAGE_NO)

it will select the rows only if exists in the table RAD_REPORT_RESULT
I need to select all the rows if there is a report or if there is no report select the data from the other tables only
example :
PATIENT_NO      Order Date          Scan Date        Release Date 
  1               15-05-2024        15-05-2024
  2               15-05-2024        15-05-2024       15-05-2024
  3               15-05-2024        15-05-2024       
  4               14-05-2024        15-05-2024
  5               14-05-2024        15-05-2024       15-05-2024


isn't this just a left join? am I missing something?
 WITH t AS (
        SELECT   
            H.PATIENT_NO,
            TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(H.SERV_REQUEST_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Order Date",
            TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(H.SERV_REQUEST_TIME, 4, '0'), 'HH24MI'), 'HH24:MI') AS "Order Time", 
            TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(G.DATE_IMAGE_TAKEN, 'yyyymmdd'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Scan Date",
            TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(G.TIME_IMAGE_TAKEN, 4, '0'), 'HH24MI'), 'HH24:MI') AS "Scan Time", 
            H.PATIENT_SOURCE_IND,
            H.PROVIDING_RESOURCE,
            G.IMAGE_NO 
        FROM   
            RAD_RESULT_VIEW H
            JOIN RAD_IMAGE_HEADER G ON H.HOSPITAL_NO = G.HOSPITAL_NO AND H.RAD_ORDER_NO = G.RAD_ORDER_NO
            JOIN MR_FILE_DETAILS A ON H.PATIENT_NO = A.PATIENT_NO
    )
    SELECT 
        t.*,  
        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(R.APPROVING_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Release Date"
    FROM 
        t
        LEFT JOIN RAD_REPORT_RESULT R ON t.IMAGE_NO = R.IMAGE_NO;


yes left join I will try it thank you :)
